# How to create a variable in javascript / jquery that contains more than one background image URL value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I developed a script that looks for a particular background image url in every div within a page. Once it finds the particular background image url, the div where it resides gets replaced by a new div. Since I wanted this to be responsive, I have four different background image urls to accommodate any screen size the user is using. All four have same background image url, the only difference is the string following the "?". The issue with my current code is it can only search for one background image url.

I've tried creating an array variable separated by "||" so my code will run if it finds any of my four images but it can only detect the first image in the array.

```
  var test = '<div>test</div>';



     $('div').each( function () {

        var bgimage = $(this).css('background-image');

        var bgimagesize = ("?&scl=2&wid=1272" || "?&scl=1&wid=822" || "?&scl=1&wid=1536" || "?&scl=1&wid=2048");

        var bgimageurl ='url("https://somewebsite.com/images/image' + bgimagesize + '")';

        if(bgimage === bgimageurl) {
          $(this).hide();
          $(this).after(test);
        } 
      });
```

I'm expecting my code to have the ability to find any of the 4 images.

Comment: Make an actual array and use: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes

Comment: "||" is a Logical operator not an array, here it's checking if the first item is true or false, since a string with contents is a truthy value, the first string is returned as the variable. Try using a Regular Expression (RegEx) to compare the url's instead.

Comment: this doesn't work either ['?&scl=2&wid=1272', '?&scl=1&wid=822', '?&scl=1&wid=1536', '?&scl=1&wid=2048']

Answer (score 0):

`"?&scl=2&wid=1272" || "?&scl=1&wid=822" .....` this will always be true in the first case because this is a hardcoded string which will always exist. You have to think about another logic to do this.

```js
const a = "foo"
const b = ""

console.log(a||b)
console.log(b||a)
console.log("hallo1"||a)
console.log("hallo1"||b)
console.log(a||"hallo2")
console.log(b||"hallo2")
```

Answer (score 0):

As other people already pointed out using the logical OR operator doesnt make sense here. 
Here is what you need to do

```
var possibleUrls = [];
var bgimagesizes = [
'url("https://somewebsite.com/images/image?&scl=2&wid=1272")',
 'url("https://somewebsite.com/images/image?&scl=1&wid=822")', 
'url("https://somewebsite.com/images/image?&scl=1&wid=1536")', 
'url("https://somewebsite.com/images/image?&scl=1&wid=2048")'
];
if (possibleUrls.includes(bgimage) { // alternatively if browser support is lacking (possibleUrls.indexOf(bgimage) !== -1)
/// code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

"||" is a Logical operator not an array, here it's checking if the first item is true or false, since a string with contents is a truthy value, the first string is returned as the variable.

```
!!"" === false
!!"something" === true

var value = ( "A" || "B" || "C" ); // value = "A"
```

Try using a Regular Expression (RegEx) to compare the url's instead:

```
var test = "<div>test</div>";

$("div").each(function() {
   var bgimage = $(this).css("background-image");

   // Must escape ? to \\? 
   // Here I create an array then "join" it into one string separated by a "|"
   var bgimagesize = [
      "\\?&scl=2&wid=1272",
      "\\?&scl=1&wid=822",
      "\\?&scl=1&wid=1536",
      "\\?&scl=1&wid=2048"
   ].join("|");

   // Create a regular expression, e.g: (A|B|C)
   var isImg = new RegExp("(" + bgimagesize + ")", "i");

   // test to see if it exists: true or false
   if (isImg.test(bgimage)) {
      $(this).hide();
      $(this).after(test);
   }
});
```

The `RegExp` creates `/(\?&scl=2&wid=1272|\?&scl=1&wid=822|\?&scl=1&wid=1536|\?&scl=1&wid=2048)/i` which is tested against `bgimage`

Check out a working example: https://codepen.io/StudioKonKon/pen/GzNPbM

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have a problem when you create the `bgimagesize` . As others already  say , you should not use the operator "||" to declare an array  . You should use `array()` or  `var bgimagesize = ["?&scl=2&wid=1272", "?&scl=1&wid=822", "?&scl=1&wid=1536", "?&scl=1&wid=2048"];` instead . After for creating `var bgimageurl` , the `map` [methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) can help you to do the job `var bgimageurl = bgimagesize.map(myImage=>'url("https://somewebsite.com/images/image' + myImage + '")';`

To check if `bgimage` is in the `bgimageurl` variable , the [method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) `includes`  can help .